# Find rows in SQL table that have specific part of value columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a table, where in a column is stored multiple ids that refer to another table. I have lets say ids 1,5 and want to find rows in the table that have that values.
Table structure is like this:

ID   SubCategory  Category(this refers to the other table)
1    a                      1,3,15
2    ab                    1,10,4
3    abc                  3,5
4    abcd                3,4,6,11
5    abcde              2,5
6    abcdef             24,3,15

SELECT * from table_name WHERE Category = "%1%" OR Category = "%5%";
Using wild cards won't return the correct rows.
Any ideas how to get the correct rows(i.e. 1,2,3,5)

Comment: What DB engine do you use? SQL-Server and MySQL are different things.

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * 
from table_name 
WHERE find_in_set(1, Category) > 0
or find_in_set(5, Category) > 0
```

#### But actually you should never store multiple values in a single column.

If you change your table design it will be much easier to select and faster because it can make use of indexes.

Comment: Note: This is mysql-specific. The question is also tagged with SQL-Server.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Did not see the SQL-Sever tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Category IN (1) OR Category IN (5);
```

Comment: If you are only guessing and don't know if this will actually work, post it as a comment instead of an answer. It's unclear when you say to try it

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that it is for mysql, but this one works on SQL-Server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #test (
id INT,
subcategory VARCHAR(100),
category VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #test values (1,    'a','1,3,15');
INSERT INTO #test values (2,    'ab','1,10,4');
INSERT INTO #test values (3,    'abc','3,5');
INSERT INTO #test values (4,    'abcd','3,4,6,11');
INSERT INTO #test values (5,    'abcde','2,5');
INSERT INTO #test values (6,    'abcdef','24,3,15');

SELECT t.* 
FROM #test t 
CROSS APPLY( SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[fnSplitString](t.category,',') a 
WHERE  CAST(splitdata AS INTEGER) = 3
) a
```